# Conditional class ordering while using Hiera with Puppet 3.7.3

Tags: ubuntu, puppet

I have two Puppet modules, "users" and "sourcerepos" called out for nodes matching a hostname expression.

"Users" creates all users required within my organization, as well as doing basic configuration for each user, such as placing an ~/.ssh/config and various keys within .ssh needed to authenticate against private Git repos.

"Sourcerepos" uses one of the created users to checkout several hundred Git repositories and place them in ~/git-repos using the puppetlabs/vcsrepos module.

The "Sourcerepos" module obviously has a dependency on the "users" module, but setting "require users" in "Sourcerepos" does not cause the entire class to be evaluated before it attempts to check out the git repositories.

Adding "before" or "subscribe" options to each repository is not feasible due to the sheer amount of repositories and the frequency that they're created.

Creating conditional operation on the vcsrepo defined type is also not viable, because of the need for it to execute differently depending on the module or class that calls it.

I *think* I understand Puppet ordering relationships, and to me, this smacks of a flaw in how one (or both) of my modules are designed. I'd like help figuring out how/why.

Comment: Can you post code that shows what you have tried? Your descriptions are a little vague.

Comment: maybe `Class['Users'] -> Class['Sourcerepos']` will do the trick? im not a big fan of chaining arrows, perhaps if you supply some example code we can help to better troubleshoot. https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_relationships.html#chaining-arrows

Answer (score 0):

Try using the new contain() function on your classes. This will ensure that a complete class is being evaluated before moving on to the next class.
This document https://www.devco.net/archives/2012/12/13/simple-puppet-module-structure-redux.php shows how you can then use classes to put your dependencies on.